# How to start appium test on iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, automation, appium

I have the following setup and trying to start the test on `iOS Simulator`. I am a beginner and don't know how to start the test. I have already imported and installed `appium` from tutorials.

**The questions are:**

> 1. Is this setup correct?
> 2. How to run the tests?

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;


    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
    import org.testng.Assert;
    import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

    public class AppiumDriver {

    private static final String JavascriptExecutor = null;
    public WebDriver driver = null;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    // set up appium
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "iOS");
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "8.1");
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM, "Mac");
    capabilities.setCapability("device", "iPhone");
    capabilities.setCapability("app", "path here, i have started it with appium inspector and it works");
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4725/wd/hub"), capabilities);

    System.out.println("App launched");
    }

    @Test
    public void test01() throws InterruptedException {
        driver.findElement(By.name("Guest")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);

     }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your setup is correct. Looks like you are using testng framework so just run it as "testng" and you should be good to go.