# How to download and open an app on XCode Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode

I've just started working on automating mobile apps. I've managed to get it working on Android, but I'm struggling with iOS.

I tried to reproduce the code from here:

[How to start appium test on iOS simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28937668/how-to-start-appium-test-on-ios-simulator)

But I can't find out how to download an app for ios simulator. I tried following this tutorial:

http://toolsqa.com/mobile-automation/appium/build-run-xcode-project/

But the "SafariLauncher.app" turned out to be a directory when it should have been a file.
Can anyone please send a link to an ios app file for the simulator that I can download? I've been searching and haven't managed to find something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, following this guide you mentioned, you need to download the .zip file from https://github.com/budhash/SafariLauncher and after unzipping it open "SafariLauncher.xcodeproj" with xCode. Next, expand "Products" directory on left side pane of xCode, right click on "SafariLauncher.app"--> Show in Finder, right click on SafariLauncher and Get Info, you will see .app location, something like "/Users//Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SafariLauncher-dnlekjshummcmegagwwtogqjbpxu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator", that is the path to your .app file. Use that path for "app" in desiredCapabilities.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. The mistake I had made was that I was expecting SafariLauncher.app to be a file.

So when I opened the terminal and found it under .../Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator the app is there, but it's a directory when I access it through the terminal.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. ;) You can run the app with Appium also, then you'll have access to elements through Appium Inspector.

Comment: Thanks, how would I run the app with Appium? Would I need to to launch it from IntelliJ?

Answer (score 0):

You can take the code and put it into an Xcode Project, then build and then click run to start up a simulator and run the app in it. When you build it, build it for testing.

Comment: I built the code and got the app running, but now I don't know how to access the app through appium inspector.
It's the line of code from the other question:     

    capabilities.setCapability("app", "path here, i have started it with appium inspector and it works");

        that is confusing me. I want to point to the location of my app file, but it hasn't created an app file (not one that I can see).